# Select query return dublicated result

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I run this query:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    thread_id,
    color_select
FROM
    order_threads
WHERE
    order_id = 42
```

I get a result like this:

| order_id | thread_id | color_select |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 | dark grey |
| 42 | 1 | off white |
| 42 | 7 | off white |
| 42 | 3 | dark grey |

I need to get more data from other tables so I rewrote the query:

```
SELECT
    order_threads.thread_id,
    order_threads.order_id,
    order_threads.color_select,
    thread.name,
    patron.id,
    patron.order_id,
    patron_colors.color_name AS color_name,
    patron_colors.id,
    patron_colors.color_count
FROM
    order_threads
JOIN 
    thread ON order_threads.thread_id = thread.id
JOIN 
    patron ON patron.order_id = order_threads.order_id
JOIN 
    patron_colors ON patron_colors.patron_id = patron.id
WHERE
    order_threads.order_id = '42'
```

The results are duplicated like this:

| thread_id | order_id | color_select | name | id | order_id | color_name | id | color_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | dark grey | blue thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 1 | 42 | dark grey | blue thread | 51 | 42 | off white | 75 | 2 |
| 1 | 42 | off white | blue thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 1 | 42 | off white | blue thread | 51 | 42 | off white | 75 | 2 |
| 7 | 42 | off white | green thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 7 | 42 | off white | green thread | 51 | 42 | off white | 75 | 2 |
| 3 | 42 | dark grey | white thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 3 | 42 | dark grey | white thread | 51 | 42 | off white | 75 | 2 |

It should be like this:

| thread_id | order_id | color_select | name | id | order_id | color_name | id | color_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | dark grey | blue thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 1 | 42 | off white | blue thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |
| 7 | 42 | off white | green thread | 51 | 42 | off white | 75 | 2 |
| 3 | 42 | dark grey | white thread | 51 | 42 | dark grey | 74 | 2 |

What is my error?

Comment: It looks like the relationship to `patron_colors` may be the issue?  What are the table definitions and what sample data exists in those tables?  If any given `patron` record has two `patron_colors` records then how will you know which to use?

Comment: the relationship between `patron_colors` and `order_threads` is on text filed contains the same value

Comment: `order_threads.color_select = patron_colors.color_name`

Comment: That's not the relationship you're using in the query.  It sounds like you may have some confusion over your own data model.

Comment: Please take a look in @sbluff answer 
I have edited the query and added this relation ship but the result return zero , i do not know why

Comment: Please take a look at the first comment above.  We don't know your table definitions, nor do we know what data is in those tables.  And if you've edited the query since posting the question then we also don't know the current state of the code.  Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself, to include `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables, `INSERT` statements for sample data, the exact query you're using, and the expected result.  You can also link to an off-side DB Fiddle (*in addition to* these details, not as a replacement for them) to easily demonstrate the behavior live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mistake in your query, the problem is that some patrons have more than one color available so you have to specify in the query that you only want to select the rows where the color of the patron matches the color of the order.

Replace

"WHERE
order_threads.order_id = '42'"
with

"WHERE
order_threads.order_id = '42' AND order_threads.color_select = patron_colors.color_name"

Comment: Thank you so much , but the result is MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: You are Right , thank you , there was a small mistake from my side , thank you

Comment: Could you mark my answer as solution in case it was? Appreciate it